# blocked by CORS :The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', Laravel8

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-api

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/objectives' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Head over to the cors.php in config folder and change this `'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],` to `'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],`

Comment: In my case, I did the reverse cos I already set headers in the .htaccess file inside the public folder.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue but now its resolved. during R&D i found many thing that i would like to share.

if you are facing this issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/api/csrf-cookie'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
> *', but only one is allowed.

[image]

Because Laravel adding two Access-Control-Allow-Origin one from
Public->index.php and other from CorsService.php that why getting this error
[image]

[image]

**Solution** is simple comment public->index file `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'` line

if you are facing this issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/api/csrf-cookie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

and your are sending request with `withCredentials: true`

**Solution:**  then you must enable Config->cors.php 'supports_credentials' => true,
if your are sending without credential true then it should be false. I hope this will help you guys. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues. In my case, I fixed it by removing

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

from my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

First solution is to use this library https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

second one is adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to your public/index.php that may fix the problem